How are signature operations like hashing or concatenating with a message done when the input is an elliptic curve point?
For a Message M, Schnorr Signature steps are

Use a scalar $p$ as private key
Public key $P = pG$ where G is the generator of an Elliptic Curve
Generate random number $q$ & compute $Q = qG$
$c = Hash(Q || M)$
$s = c * p + q\mod\ell$ where $\ell$ is the group order

$(Q,s)$ is the Schnorr Signature

How does one concatenate $Q||M$ when $Q$ is an elliptic curve point? What is the output type? Can it be directly used as input for a standard hash function like SHA256?

Are there standard ways to do this?

The standard ways to encode elliptic curve points to byte strings are outlined in the SEC 1 document section 2.3.3
There is a choice to use a compressed or uncompressed form. In both cases the full 0-leading byte representation of the $x$-coordinate is used. In the compressed case, the byte 02 or 03 is prepended according to the parity of the $y$-coordinate; in the uncompressed case the full 0-leading byte representation of the $y$-coordinate is prepended, with an extra leading 04 byte. The point at infinity is represented with a single 00 byte. These bytes can be used as input to a standard hash function such as SHA3 or SHA256.
These byte strings are often subsequently encoded into DER, PEM, or X962 formats for some applications.

I would like to note that, adding $y$ doesn't increase the security, since 2 bits is enough to determine $y$
